# Want value from javascript in Jquery, this is php?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am following this example - http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#serialize and would like to be able to set the value of a hidden input field based on the user selection. So rather than the value being displayed as per the example, that value instead would be consecutively added to the hidden input field value. How can I achieve this?

`<input type="hidden" />`

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: You have to go to the Link I have provided.
It is an example of JQuery.

The value returned by selecting it in the html, but I want to put this value in < input type = "hidden"/>.

Comment: `selected value will be in the form of HTML`, so do you want the selected values to be translated into hidden fields?

Comment: So, suppose I selected values 1, 2, and 3. Should it look like `<input type="hidden" name="values" value="1,2,3">`?

Comment: @DaveChen Yes, you are.

Comment: _"You have to go to the Link I have provided"_ - No, _you_ have to write a more detailed question that explains clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the selected value to be placed in your hidden field, add a class or id to your hidden input, and then change the following lines from the source example page:

your hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput" />
```

from the example, change

```
var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
```

to your hidden input

```
var result = $('#hiddenInput').empty();
```

then change

```
result.append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );
```

to

```
result.val('#' + (index + 1));
```

to add the values rather than replace them, change the line to

```
result.val(result.val() + "#" + ( index + 1 ) );
```

here is a working example - http://jsfiddle.net/DBuVf/1

Comment: But I suspect that

If you select multiple time slots, such as select .append channels 1, 3, 5, the value will be the value of the array is 3.

But enough change to get the last value val one.

If we want to have all three, and is in the form that I want to do it or not.

Comment: I updated the answer for you so that it adds each value to the hidden input